# My mac Automator Application script is not working with two arguments

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

On my Catalina mac, I have this Mac Automator shell script to remove all metadata from image files as follows:

```
for f in "$@"
do
/usr/local/bin/exiftool -all= "$f"
done
```

Now this utility exiftool by default makes a backup of the original image file and it works OK. However, exiftool has another option "-overwrite_original" which can be added to the command line as follows:

```
exiftool -overwrite_original -all= filename
```

My problem is that when I add the other option (overwrite) to the Automator shell script above, the script just doesn't work. Is there any syntax problem that I need to fix?

Comment: It’s the script in Automator doesn’t work with two options in the command.

Comment: When I add -overwrite_original to the automator shell script command above, the metadata doesn’t get removed. Can you post the automator shell script please?

Answer (score 1):

From **Terminal** on **macOS Catalina 10.15.1**, `exiftool -ver` returns `11.78`.

I used the `ExifTool-11.78.dmg` from https://exiftool.org to install it.

`exiftool -all= filename` does not make a backup, nor does `exiftool -overwrite_original -all= filename`; however, in both cases a `filename_exiftool_tmp` file is created during the process and I'm just left with `filename` when the process completes.

---

As an example, I take a screenshot of the **Desktop** and just use `exiftool filename` from **Terminal** and it prints out 90 lines of *metadata*.

Then I use **Automator** on it, then back in **Terminal** using `exiftool filename` it prints out 20 lines of *metadata*.

The *metadata* of the 20 lines left **cannot** be removed by `exiftool`.

I then run `exiftool -all= filename` from **Terminal** and it prints `0 image files updated` and `1 image files unchanged`.

This is exactly as it should be as some of the information is not being pulled from the *file* when queried by `exiftool`. 
Some of that info comes for the *filesystem*, attributes of the *file* and what info is shown that comes from within the *file* just cannot be removed by `exiftool` and I've actually read that somewhere within the documentation, whether it be at https://exiftool.org, or from where I just don't remember exactly where, sorry.